# Using up arrow in Visual Studio IntelliSense to select the last item

Tags: visual-studio, ide, intellisense

Anyone knows if this is possible? I tried it in vs 2005 and 2008 and it doesn't do that. IMO this would be a very useful feature when I know I want to select the last item or an item that's closer to the end of the IntelliSense list.

Comment: I like using the Up Arrow to select the previous item in the list...

Comment: I think I misunderstood...  I guess Joan means to select the last item if you're at the top of the list and hit the up arrow.  *wishes comments were editable*

Comment: Yeah that's how it would work. But also when the IntelliSense list is brand new for a particular class for instance then it gives no selection, and down arrow selects the first and up arrow should be able to select the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. I hit Page Down repeatedly to get to the last item if absolutely needed. Normally I just hit the first letter of what I need next, then select it.

Comment: It's a shame. Have you seen in in vs 2010?

Comment: I think the wrap around effect would be less desirable, IMO.

Comment: Why? If I know to pick ToString, which is generally last, I would like to do it using the up arrow.

Comment: If I would like to pick ToString, I would like to do it by typing T. This would be much faster than hitting the up arrow in many cases. Think of the fact that (at least for C#) IntelliSense remembers the last entry selected, so pressing the up arrow would not lead you to the last entry.

Comment: continued: I think the "remember"-feature of IntelliSense is a much better time-saver than a cyclic scrolling would be.

Comment: I agree, but think of the cases where the IntelliSense list is brand new, say when you are overriding the ToString for several classes, then you don't get the last used item.